# Is there a token I can use to display a node's view mode?

Tags: rules, tokens

I am trying to use Rules to send an email with the results of the submission of a node. Is there any way to place the entire contents of the node using a token?

```
e.g. [node:teaser]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Advanced Entity Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/aet) module.

> Advanced Entity Tokens (AET) Creates a Token for each of your entity
>   items.
>
> Through AET you can query the DB for entities using Tokens.
>
> **Examples**
>
> - [aet:node:1] will return the 1st node with the token view mode (or
>     full if token is not available).
> - [aet:file:1:view-original] will
>     return the 1st file entity with the original view mode.
> - [aet:taxonomy_term:1:name] will return the 1st node title field (note
>     that this level of chaining is done by the formal token implementation
>     of the node entity in token/token.tokens.inc -> token_token_info()).
>
> **Real World Examples**
>
> - Displaying a node inside a block: This could be done using Node Block
>     OR you could insert a token inside a block you create through the
>     Blocks interface that retrieves a certain node (or a property inside a
>     node, [aet:node:] or [aet:node::body]) with no extra code.
> - Displaying a File Entity (image) inside a title field: I'm not sure
>     how this could have been done without custom code, BUT with AET you
>     could easily insert the Token for a specific File Entity
>     ([aet:file:]) and your entity will be displayed. AET defaults to
>     the Token view mode if available (full otherwise), but you could just
>     as easily specify a view mode of your own
>     ([aet:file::view-teaser]).
> - I'm saving this spot for real life
>     examples other Drupal users had (or thought of having) for this
>     module.